# Помогите сделать сортировку по алфавиту!

Tags: c++, сортировка, visual-c++

Нужно сделать сортировку по алфавиту фамилий, которые мы вводим с клавиатуры, такое вообще возможно?
чтобы сортировалось всё опираясь на введенные данные в "string NameSurname"

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
    class NOTE {
      public: string NameSurname, Number;
      int Bday[3];
      NOTE() {
        NameSurname="Иванов Иван";
        Number="+79872458766";
        for (int i=0;
        i < 2;
        i++) {
          Bday[i]=1;
        }
        Bday[2]=2001;
      }
      friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const NOTE&);
      friend istream& operator>>(istream&, const NOTE&);
    };
    ostream& operator << (ostream& os, NOTE& numb) //описание функции перегрузки оператора вывода
    {
      os << "ФИО: " << numb.NameSurname << endl << "Номер телефона: " << numb.Number << endl << "Дата рождения:";
      for (int i=0;
      i < 3;
      i++) {
        os << numb.Bday[i] << ".";
      }
      os << endl << endl;
      return os;
    }

    istream& operator>>(istream& is, NOTE& student) //описание функции перегрузки оператора ввода
    {
      cin.ignore();
      cout << "Введите ФИО: ";
      getline(is, student.NameSurname);
      cout << "Введите номер телефона: ";
      is>>student.Number;
      cout << "Введите дату рождения: ";
      for (int i=0;
      i < 3;
      i++) {
        is>>student.Bday[i];
      }
      return is;
    }

    int main() {
      setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
      SetConsoleCP(1251);
      SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
      ifstream in("InZnak.txt");
      ofstream out;
      out.open("OutZnak.txt");
      NOTE note[8]; //создаем массив класса
      start: пункта меню system("cls");
      cout << "Выберите пункт: " << endl;
      cout << "1.Ввести данные вручную" << endl;
      cout << "2.Отсортировать список по фамилиям" << endl;
      cout << "3.Выход" << endl;
      int vibor;
      cout << "Выбор: ";
      cin>>vibor;
      system("cls");
      switch (vibor) {
        default: {
          cout << "Неверная команда. Введите снова:" << endl;
          system("pause");
          goto start;
        }
        case 1: {
          for (int i=0;
          i < 8;
          i++) {
            cin>>note[i];
          }
          system("pause");
          goto start;
        }
        case 2: //Сюда нужна сортировка по фамилиям                 
        {
          for (int i=0;
          i < 8;
          i++) {
            for (int j=i + 1;
            j < 8;
            j++) {}
          }
          /*for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if (note[i].Bday[1] > note[j].Bday[1])
                    { swap(note[i], note[j]); }
                }
            }*/
          system("pause");
          goto start;
        }
        case 3: {
          cout << "Exit...";
          return 0;
        }
      }
    }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NOTE note[8];

sort(note, note+8, 
     [](const auto& a, const auto& b){ return a.NameSurname < b.NameSurname; });
```

Примерно так...

Comment: Вместо сортировки оно теперь ничего не выводит ((

Comment: Ну так если бездумно сунуть... Откуда мне изнать, **ЧТО** вы там делали? У вас в коде вообще никакого вывода нет!